# SQL Query to get number of times and duration of a column values reaches a specific value in a sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns **ReceivedOn**(Date/Time) and **Speed**(int)
Sample data will look like below

```
     ReceivedOn       |   Speed
 ----------------------------------------------
 2012-11-05 06:30:00          10
 2012-11-05 06:31:00          45
 2012-11-05 06:32:00          48
 2012-11-05 06:33:00          53
 2012-11-05 06:34:00          47
 2012-11-05 06:35:00          38
 2012-11-05 06:36:00          22
 2012-11-05 06:37:00          36
 2012-11-05 06:38:00          41
 2012-11-05 06:39:00          47
 2012-11-05 06:40:00          49
 2012-11-05 06:41:00          22
 2012-11-05 06:42:00          36
```

I need to group the rows when speed > 40, so that the resulting output would be

```
       StartTime      |   EndTime               |  Count
 --------------------------------------------------------
 2012-11-05 06:31:00     2012-11-05 06:34:00         4
 2012-11-05 06:38:00     2012-11-05 06:40:00         3
```

StartTime to be the ReceivedOn value when the speed first crossed 40, and the EndTime value to be the ReceivedOn value when it was last over 40 in consecutive records, with the Count being the total number of consecutive records that were over 40.

I tried my best but unable to get it. Is it possible to get this with sql query?
Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont really get the question, Can you give more details exactly what you are trying to achieve? Thanks

Comment: If I understand it correctly, he's wanting the `StartTime` to be the ReceivedOn value when the speed first crossed 40, and the `EndTime` value to be the ReceivedOn value when it was last over 40 in consecutive records, with the `Count` being the total number of consecutive records that were over 40.

Comment: exactly as @Siyual said. I have edited my question.

Comment: Also, post what have you tried. So whe know that you are not asking us to do some homework.

Comment: Do you have any time gaps? Or is every minute represented? If you have gaps, how should they be handled in your output result set?

Comment: @OllieJones Time gap is not fixed. it is variable. I have to find each occurrence of speed crossing some x limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general answer to questions like these. 
[Detect consecutive items meeting particular criteria in a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109404/detect-consecutive-items-meeting-particular-criteria-in-a-time-series/17139667#17139667)

Your specific case seems to be easier because you have no time gaps (said he hopefully). You are trying to find the gaps in your time sequence. In your case the gaps are defined as those items that are >= 40.  So, you're looking for gaps in the sequence of events with values less than forty.

Here's a query that gives your time squence with row numbers.

```
SELECT @RowA := @RowA + 1 AS ROWNUM,
       ReceivedOn, Speed
   FROM (
        SELECT ReceivedOn, Speed
          FROM obs
         WHERE NOT Speed >= 40
   ) AS A
   JOIN (SELECT @RowA := 0) AS B
```

Now you use a some serious SQL monkey business to self-join this sequence to itself. That works like this:

```
SELECT B.ReceivedON + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE As StartTime,
       A.ReceivedOn - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AS EndTime,
       -1 + TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, B.ReceivedOn, A.ReceivedOn) AS Count
  FROM (
         SELECT @RowA := @RowA + 1 AS ROWNUM,
                ReceivedOn, Speed
           FROM (
              SELECT ReceivedOn, Speed
                FROM obs
               WHERE NOT Speed >= 40
                ) AS A
           JOIN (SELECT @RowA := 0) AS B
       ) AS A
  JOIN (
          SELECT @RowB := @RowB + 1 AS ROWNUM,
                 ReceivedOn, Speed
         FROM (
              SELECT ReceivedOn, Speed
                FROM obs
               WHERE NOT Speed >= 40
              ) AS A
         JOIN (SELECT @RowB := 0) AS B
        ) AS B ON B.ROWNUM+1 = A.ROWNUM
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, B.ReceivedOn, A.ReceivedOn) > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cb57/24/0

This looks really hairy, but it is simply a join of that first query to itself `ON B.ROWNUM+1 = A.ROWNUM`. That lines up that query's result set to itself offset by one row, so you can compare consecutive rows.

That gives the result you need. Notice that if your first observation is >= 40, this query will leave out the first sequence of observations.

Comment: Thank you @Ollie Jones. But sadly the time gaps between records are not fixed. It can be seconds, minutes or some times hours. Otherwise it would have been a great solution. I have to find each occurrence of speed crossing some x limit say 40 in sample data. Start time and end time of that occurrence.